# Override base Google Cloud Storage URL in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, emulation

I'm trying to setup a [local emulator of GCP storage](https://github.com/oittaa/gcp-storage-emulator) (unofficial) to work with the [.NET client library](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest). However I'm not sure how to override the base storage URL which seems to be hardcoded as `storage.googleapis.com`.
I've seen `STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST` param in the emulator description, but it doesn't seem to work with .NET Client library :|

I've checked the library code a little bit and I found this coude in the internal `StorageService` class:

[image]

Is there any way to override the `BaseUri` in .NET 6 / Core?

Parts of my code / configuration for reference:

```
// Configuration
private static void AddGcpServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    // Dev only for now
    var storageClient = StorageClient.CreateUnauthenticated();
    services.AddSingleton(storageClient);
    services.AddSingleton<ICloudStorage, CloudStorage>();
}
    

// ...
// Storage
public class CloudStorage : ICloudStorage
{
    private readonly StorageClient _client;

    public CloudStorage(StorageClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    

    public async Task<Uri> SaveFile(string containerName, string fullSavePath, Stream file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await _client.UploadObjectAsync(containerName, fullSavePath, null, source: file,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        return result.MediaLink.ToUri();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was looking through docs I found [this sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#storage-set-client-endpoint-csharp):

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;

public class SetClientEndpointSample
{
    public StorageClient SetClientEndpoint(string endpoint) => new StorageClientBuilder
    {
        BaseUri = endpoint,
        UnauthenticatedAccess = true // Change for Production
    }.Build();
}
```

Turns out you just need to create the client through `StorageClientBuilder` :)

Comment: Can you please post complete answer cause I'm getting IO Error when reading bucket using this approach.

Comment: @user1765862 this sample worked for me, it may be the case that you face a different problem. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: can you please show how do you start container (exact command)

Comment: I'm getting `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. `

Comment: `gcp-storage-emulator start --port=40042 --host=localhost &` 
I didn't use it in Docker because of some issues: https://github.com/oittaa/gcp-storage-emulator/issues/210

Comment: Although it kind of worked in docker apart from the above. You can see my sample repo:
https://github.com/Rashair/gcp-storage-emulator-example/tree/main